# Combine multiple Google sheets that can keep updating

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have an app writing automatically my health data into a Google sheet.
It does so in three different sheets inside one file.
Column A is always the date.
Now, I'd like to have a master sheet that combines this data.

Like this:

**SHEET1:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/07/21 | value1 |  |
| 19/07/21 | value2 |  |

**SHEET 2:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/07/21 |  | value3 |
| 18/07/21 |  | value4 |

**RESULT:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/07/21 | value1 | value3 |
| 19/07/21 | value2 |  |
| 18/07/21 |  | value4 |

So, I'd like to sort by date and combine the values from the two sheets into one line for one date per day.
Is that even possible?

I've tried different queries and IMPORTRANGEs, but to no avail.

Comment: The link provided by the OP in a comment is no longer available. This is one example of why it must include all the relevant data directly into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

`={{"Date", "1", "2"};Query(ArrayFormula(query({query({Sheet1!A1:C2;Sheet2!A1:C2},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 label Col1 'Date', Col2 '1', Col3 '2'")},"Select Col1, "&ArrayFormula(join(", ","Max(Col"&column(B1:C1)&")"))&"group by Col1",1)),"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc",0)}`

- `{"Date", "1", "2"}`: created Column headers
- `query({Sheet1!A1:C2;Sheet2!A1:C2},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 label Col1 'Date', Col2 '1', Col3 '2'")`: combines the data from "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"
- `ArrayFormula(join(", ","Max(Col"&column(B1:C1)&")"))`: `Max`is one of the few aggregation functions that work on strings; "strings are compared alphabetically, with case-sensitivity." So instead of returning a number (such as with `count`, `MAX` returns a string which works well in this scenarion since since there is only one string value per date per column.

---

**Output**

[image: snapshot]

---

Credit: [Infospired: Formula to Combine Duplicate Rows in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/formula-to-combine-duplicate-rows/)